# No reply so I went ahead

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to find the word that means that follows:  A question or instruction is given, but no reply is made.  The assumption is that since no one has replied that it is okay to go ahead.  For example "Can I have next Tuesday off as annual leave?"  Since the manager did not come back and say "No", my assumption was that it was okay.  I know that there is a word for this, but cannot remember what it is.

Comment: The standard (jocular) phrase is "***silence is consent***". But ... it's dangerous. You've been warned.

Comment: *No news is good news.*

Comment: You might be thinking of [acquiescence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/acquiescence), but as Dan Bron warned you, don't rely on it here (or elsewhere). The reign of "no means no" was short-lived. "Yes means (& requires a) yes" is now the standard.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a single word, but you are applying ***implied consent***:

> **Implied consent** is consent which is not expressly granted by a person, but rather inferred from a person's actions and the facts and circumstances of a particular situation (or in some cases, by a person's silence or inaction).
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implied_consent)</sub>